how to solve Geopandas error when using SCHEME
I am trying to plot my geodataframe 'GDF' with the 'scheme' argument.
This is what a subset of GDF looks like (the actual dataset is about 100 points with values ranging from 1-30):
                                    geometry  test
NAME_2                                                                         
Almere          POINT (145733.407 486577.233)                              11.0
Terschelling    POINT (151460.757 601487.681)                              11.0
Nijmegen        POINT (186470.194 427982.773)                              14.0
Wijchen         POINT (177163.100 425493.948)                              12.0
Groningen       POINT (238013.219 582041.952)                              33.0
Tilburg         POINT (133849.445 399500.242)                              14.0
Amsterdam       POINT (121311.987 487284.923)                              19.0
Haarlemmermeer  POINT (107375.868 480200.031)                              12.0
Utrecht         POINT (133888.767 455940.327)                              18.0
Delft            POINT (84745.471 446073.406)                              12.0
Leiden           POINT (93373.429 463325.293)                              13.0

The following line works for me:
GDF.plot(ax=base, column = 'test', cmap = 'YlGn',legend=True)

However, adding the 'scheme' argument results in python getting stuck (no error message, it just hangs):
GDF.plot(ax=base, column = 'test', cmap = 'YlGn',scheme='Quantiles', alpha=.8, edgecolor='None',legend=True)

I found a similar question, but unfortunately that question did not get answered. I have also tried the 'NaturalBreaks' scheme as a test, but that gave the same problem. I am not sure how to proceed now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

do you have mapclassify installed and working? (import mapclassify as mc mc.__version__)
